# How can I create a report of a github "Projects" Kanban board ("Projects" tab of a repository)

Tags: github, github-projects

Is there a way to extract the data of a github "Projects" Kanban board?

I'm talking about the Kanban boards that can be added to a repo. Found here:
`https://github.com/<<user-name>>/<<repo-name>>/projects/`

What I need is a way to export the information about which tasks were moved to which columns at what time/date. The data can be in any format but if there is a tool that generates a nice report I'd prefer that.